# How to dynamically render angular(typescript) html in Asp.net core through HttpWebRequest?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular5

I want full angular html through HttpWebRequest from .Net Core.

I have tried using HttpWebRequest and I also get html but in that angular is not loaded. I am getting index.html page but the html inside '' is not getting loaded in .Net-Core.

```
 private string GetPageContent(string url){
     var httpRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
      httpRequest.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds;
        var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                return result;
            }
```

I expect the output of result to be html with angular loaded means I want inner html of selector '', but the expected output is html without angular loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Angular create html markup via javascript on client side. To receive generated html You cat use Selenium, which use your browser to get ready markup. [Selenium c# tutorial](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/)